# How to get the last bar index of the currently displayed bars in the window?

Tags: pine-script

I want to label the last bar in the current window. `barstate.islast` is true only for the overall last bar in the whole dataset. I need to figure out the last bar that is displayed on my window. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in Pine.
There's no way to interact with what's shown in the window.

Edit 1 : `last_bar_index`
While it's still not possible to get the last bar that is displayed in the window, it is now possible to get the `bar_index` of the last bar in the set of bars, by using the built-in variable [last_bar_index](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_last_bar_index)

Comment: Added Edit 1 : last_bar_index

Answer (score 0):

Now with Pinescript v5, you can get the number of the visibles bars on your screen.
Just import this open library

```
import mentalRock19315/NumberOfVisibleBars/3
```

And then you can get the number of the visibles bars in a variable of your choice :

```
a = NumberOfVisibleBars. NumberOfVisibleBars()
```